# Java code to compare two cron expressions?

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

**How to compare two cron expressions.**
We have a condition like we need to compare two cron expressions and need yo check whether both are equal or not

Eg:
"0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *" = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *" then i need to proceed
otherwise need to throw error.

Comment: That expressions are stings. Why you do not compare the strings?

Comment: if(cron1.equals(cron2)) 
{
  //do stuff
}
else
{
  throw new Exception("Crons do not match")
}

Comment: If you don't want to compare Strings, but the next valid time (in case the crons are different but might result in the same time) maybe this post is usefull?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632880/compare-cron-expression-with-current-time

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can go with something like this:

```
    String str1 = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *";
    String str2 = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *";
    if (str1.equals(str2)) {
        // do what you want
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Strings do not match");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is valid, though the example is bad. Consider the following cases:

```
cron1 = "* * * * MON"//unix
cron2 = "*/1 * * * 1"//unix
cron3= "0 * * * *"//unix
cron4="0 * * * * MON *"//quartz
//now we compare crons
cron1.equivalent(cron2) -> true
cron1.equivalent(cron3) -> false
cron1.equivalent(cron4) -> true
```

If you are looking for some library that would allow you to perform such comparisons, have a look at [cron-utils](https://github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils)

After parsing a cron expression, will create a Cron object, which has a method to compare crons.